# Why will Discord not accept my JSON table?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, discord

**My goal is to post Google Forms responses to a Discord channel via a webhook. I'm using Google Apps Script in order to do this.**

I'm expecting a regular case of the webhook being posted whenever I submit the form, though Discord always throws back `{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}`.

Is there something wrong with the code I have written that would poison the JSON beyond use?

Here is the code that the `onFormSubmit` trigger would be using.

Assume that `webHookURL` is correct.
`messageTemplate` is the exact JSON that has been sent by the trigger after formatting has been performed in `onFormSubmission` and I have tested `messageTemplate` in a separate function that just sends it after performing `JSON.stringify` on it.

```
let messageTemplate = {
    "content": "Test",
    "embeds": [{
        "color": 10751,
        "fields": [
      {
          "name": "Question 1",
          "value": "Option 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Question 2",
        "value": "Test"
      }
    ]
    }]
}

function onFormSubmission(e) {
  let FormResponse = e.response;
  let QuestionResponses = FormResponse.getItemResponses();
  let newMessage = messageTemplate

  for (var i = 0; i < QuestionResponses.length; i++) {
    let QuestionResponse = QuestionResponses[i];
    let fieldName = QuestionResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    let fieldValue = QuestionResponse.getResponse();

    newMessage.embeds[0].fields[i] = { "name": fieldName, "value": fieldValue };
  }

  let requestPayload = JSON.stringify(newMessage)

  let requestOptions = {
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    payload: requestPayload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  }

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webHookURL, requestOptions)

  Logger.log("POSTed")
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
  Logger.log(requestOptions.payload);
}
```

P.S: I have scoured this site already for all related questions and attempted to implement fixes, but nothing has helped my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found it!**

I missed an `s` in `header`.